# Send stdin to a process from windows command prompt

Tags: windows, console, stdin

In Windows I have console programs that run in the background with the console hidden. Is there anyway to direct input to the programs console? I want to be able to do something like:

```
echo Y| *the_running_process_here*
```

to send Y to the process' stdin.

Comment: Doing it with console may be a tough ask, but an option like a wrapper python script, which launches the console program as a child process.  It can listen to a socket or something and then pass the command to stdin of the console program?

Comment: @TarunLalwani - I guess that's why it never got an answer. I would like a definitive, "It can't be done because..." answer if there is no "here's how to do it..." answer.

Comment: Is the process already running, or should it run as part of the command?

Comment: Hi @KfirDadosh - the process is already running

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible by basic `cmd` commands. [PowerShell](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) is more powerful though and can use the .NET framework from windows.

I found this PowerShell script which claims to pass text to an already opened `cmd`:

```bsh
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
$psi.FileName = "cmd.exe"; #process file
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false; #start the process from it's own executable file
$psi.RedirectStandardInput = $true; #enable the process to read from standard input

$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi);

Start-Sleep -s 2 #wait 2 seconds so that the process can be up and running

$p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir"); #StandardInput property of the Process is a .NET StreamWriter object
```

<sub>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16100200/10588376</sub>

You would have to safe this script with an `.ps1` ending and run it.

**A workaround to use this as a `cmd` command would be to make it accept arguments, so that you can run it with `yourScript.ps1 procced_pid arguments` for example.**

The standard windows `cmd` is just too limited to fullfill such a task by its own.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what this script is doing? If the process I want to send stdin to is already running, how does this script know which process I mean?

Comment: @MoragHughson just use [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.4) and it'll also return the `Diagnostics.Process` as above