# Can I send some text to the STDIN of an active process under Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, process, batch-file, console

I searched the web for that question and landed on Server Fault:

**[Can I send some text to the STDIN of an active process running in a screen session?](https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi)**

Seems like it is ridiculously easy to achieve this under Linux. But I need it for a Win32 Command Prompt.

Background: I have an application that polls STDIN and if I press the <kbd>x</kbd> key, the application terminates. Now, I want to do some automated testing, test the application and then shut it down.

**Note**: Just killing the process is not an option since I'm currently investigating problems that arise during the shutdown of my application.

Comment: This might be difficult to do in batch file but if you are using Windows Powershell, you can instantiate a Process object, call it's 'Start' method to run your application and then give text input to the process's 'StandardInput' property.

Comment: @Abbas: If you could elaborate a bit more on this (i.e. code sample), you would earn rep...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

.NET framework's [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) and [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) classes can be used to create and control a process. Since Windows PowerShell can be used to instantiate .NET objects, the ability to control almost every aspect of a process is available from within PowerShell.

Here's how you can send the `dir` command to a `cmd.exe` process (make sure to wrap this in a .ps1 file and then execute the script):

```
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
$psi.FileName = "cmd.exe"; #process file
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false; #start the process from it's own executable file
$psi.RedirectStandardInput = $true; #enable the process to read from standard input

$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi);

Start-Sleep -s 2 #wait 2 seconds so that the process can be up and running

$p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir"); #StandardInput property of the Process is a .NET StreamWriter object
```

Comment: Getting exception:
Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied"
At C:\git\a.ps1:9 char:1
+ $p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

Comment: @Piepypye It sounds like you're trying to run a program or cmdlet that requires Administrator privileges. Try adding `$psi.Verb = "runas"` before starting the process. This will ask your OS for elevated permissions through UAC in Windows.