# Is it possible to start a subprocess and creates pipes for stdin/stdout using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I've looked at the PowerShell documentation for how to start a subprocess and create pipes for stdin/stdout.

However, I cannot seem to find any information on the subject.

What I want to achieve is somewhat similar to the C++ code at MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Does PowerShell provide equivalent functionality as a scripting language?

Comment: What is your end goal?  What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?  In any case you might want to look at this related question: [Can I send some text to the STDIN of an active process under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098366/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-under-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here an example of a subprocess, the standard output gets redirected to a file. You have to specify in detail, what you want to do.

```
scriptBlock = {

    "Hello World" | Out-File -FilePath 'd:\jobTest.txt'

 }

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Comment: Thank you - I want to implement a netcat-like client in PowerShell. In particular, I want to: 1) Connect  a TCP socket, 2) Start a CMD.exe subprocess, 3) Create a pipe between socket and CMD.exe. Any ideas? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. I would do this using runspaces and a synchronized hash for data exchange between job 1 (socket) and job 2 (cmd).

Comment: Is it possible to give a small example, or would it fill too much?

Comment: Okay, I see how runspaces work. But it seems that I can only retrieve output after the `BeginInvoke()` completes?

Comment: This is a good excample for introduction:
https://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/19/sharing-variables-and-live-objects-between-powershell-runspaces/