# Using System.Diagnostics.Process to input a y to a Plink on standard input?

Tags: powershell, ssh, putty, plink

How do I pass a `Y` into a process started by a `System.Diagnostic.Process` in PowerShell?

```
function Start-NewPlinkProcess(
        [string]$pfile = 'plink.exe',
        [string]$arguments = 'somehost -l somelogin -pw somepasswd ping -c 12 someOtherHost > /home/homeie/mePingTestResults.txt'
    ){
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process;
    $p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false;
    $p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true;
    $p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true;
    $p.StartInfo.FileName = $pfile;
    $p.StartInfo.Arguments = $arguments
    $p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y") # Pass a Y to stdin ignore that...
    $pident = ($p.Start()).Id
    Write-Host("pid: $($pident)");
    #$p.WaitForExit();
    #$p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    return $p
}
```

When I call it I still get:

```
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n)
```

I've read elsewhere that it's possible to try something like `echo y | plink ...` and have it read it in piped from standard input, but I want to have more control over it then just that.

Comment: At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=netframework-4.7.2 they don't write to StandardInput till aftter the process is started.  Not sure whether that is the issue or not.

Comment: @KoryGill Yup, that's it; I actually found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098366/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-under-windows it's just confusing because in the `echo y | plink` statement it comes before it so you'd think there would be no waiting piping from standard input and you'd think that it would run echo first...but I guess not.  Even in order of operations...I'd think it'd be run first but I guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your StandardInput line below where the process is started.

```
function Start-NewPlinkProcess(
        [string]$pfile = 'plink.exe',
        [string]$arguments = 'somehost -l somelogin -pw somepasswd ping -c 12 someOtherHost > /home/homeie/mePingTestResults.txt'
    ){
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process;
    $p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false;
    $p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true;
    $p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true;
    $p.StartInfo.FileName = $pfile;
    $p.StartInfo.Arguments = $arguments
    $pident = ($p.Start()).Id
    Write-Host("pid: $($pident)");
    $p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y") # Pass a Y to stdin ignore that...
    #$p.WaitForExit();
    #$p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    return $p
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Do not!**

Verifying host key fingerprint is an integral part of securing your connection. Blindly accepting any host key will make you vulnerable to the [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

---

Instead, use the [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey) to provide the fingerprint of the expected/known host key.

```
[string]$arguments = 'somehost -l somelogin -pw somepasswd ping -hostkey xx:xx:xx:xx:... -c 12 someOtherHost > /home/homeie/mePingTestResults.txt'
```

Comment: I like this.  My answer was just to accomplish what the OP was asking but this is a more complete answer!

Comment: I know it's wrong.  I'm doing it because I have no other choice.  I'm being rushed into higher numbers and we just press `y` anyway.