# Escape from SSH host verification on use of Plink session in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, putty, plink

I'm creating an application is C#, and I've just encounter a problem with PuTTY's SSH host verification.

When trying to run a Plink session.

When I already ran this specific host already I run into host key caching problem.

Like this:

> If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
>   adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
>   If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
>   connection.
>   Store key in cache? (y/n)

The idea that I want to write "yes" automatically.

After I've been done some digging on the internet I found a solution to pass:

```
echo y | plink.exe <the rest of arguments>
```

But the problem that I'm using the following code:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = Path.Combine(@"plink.exe"),
        Arguments = string.Format(@"-L {0}:{1}:{2} {3}@{4} -pw ""{5}"" -N -v", {Local forwarding port}, "localhost", {Host port}, "root", ProxyIpAfterPicked, textBox2.Text),
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
```

I've noticed that some peoples examples that pass `StreamWriter.Writeline("y")`, but it doesn't work either.
Is there any way to work with that specific code just to add Arguments to it or something I'm really clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Never pass `y` to blindly accept any host key. You lose security by doing so.
  For the correct solution, see:
  [How to pass echo y to plink.exe for first connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552236/850848) or
  [Using System.Diagnostics.Process to input a y to a Plink on standard input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54227684/850848)
- Do not use external application to implement SSH. Use some native .NET SSH library, like [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, question was modified accordingly, SSH.NET able to raise a plink session?

Comment: SSH.NET has nothing to do with Plink. SSH.NET is native SSH implementation for .NET. It can do (almost) anything you might need with SSH, without a dependence on 3rd party software like Plink.

Comment: I'll try to implement this approach... Thanks.